# 'Sprint Layout': How do I flip the track layout to place component symbols?

Tags: software

1. I have a photo of my through-hole boards copper side, tracks and solder.
2. I used the: Extras-Scanned Copy, option and imported the image. I choose: **'C1'** (*Copper-one*) right at the bottom of the GUI-window and picked **'Board Side1 - Top**' because this board has just the silk-screen side and copper (it's not multi-layered).
3. I then drew over my image and marked out the tracks and pads.

*I need to flip the track-layout so that I can insert components from the library.* I tried selecting **'S1'** for Silkscreen side but my tracks didn't flip over. I guess I could continue and populate it just the same but I wanted to confirm if this was the right thing to do. **How do I then generate a schematic from the layout?**

More on what I'm trying to do here: [Reverse engineer a simple populated PCB](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4585/software-for-drawing-circuit-schematics/)

[image]

Comment: Check this answer out: [How can I reverse engineer a simple through-hole board?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/80528/29792)

Comment: I would first flip or mirror the picture of the board in an image editor, so you can work on it as if looking at the top of the board.